# Why only heat energy is linked with entropy?

Tags: entropy

While calculating the change in entropy why do we only consider the change in heat energy?

Is it because entropy means randomness and for randomness the more the average kinetic energy of particles the more random it is again only heat energy can increase kinetic energy?

Comment: One can argue that mixing two different fluid substances increases entropy because it usually takes a LOT of work to unmix them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While calculating the change in entropy why do we only consider the
> change in heat energy?

No. Entropy can be generated without any heat transfer. An example is an irreversible adiabatic process. It generates entropy without any heat transfer. You need to differentiate entropy transfer, which occurs for a reversible transfer of heat, from entropy generation, which occurs in any irreversible process, whether it be an irreversible heat transfer or irreversible work.

> Is it because entropy means randomness and for randomness the more the
> average kinetic energy of particles the more random it is again only
> heat energy can increase kinetic energy?

There's a bit more to it than this. Ordinarily, an increase in temperature, all other things being equal, means an increase in entropy. But a reversible adiabatic compression of an ideal gas increases its temperature without increasing entropy. Although the average kinetic energy of the gas molecules has increased the volume of the gas has decreased reducing the available space for the molecules. The net effect is no increase in entropy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 3):

Entropy is related either with heat or with irreversible work. If you do irreversible work on a thermodynamic system it also increases the amount of entropy and, after a while, it is impossible to tell whether this increase in entropy has come from heating the system or from some kind of quick jerking or stirring --once the disturbances have "flattened out", so to speak.
There is a precise way to assign a number to the amount of information contained in a system. This quantity is called "volume of phase space". The essence of it is contained in Liouville's theorem.
Entropy is, as you say, randomness. Is the amount of this abstract volume --measured in (momentum)x(displacement)-- that is not described by your macroscopic parameters --usually volume, and pressure, but perhaps others, like number of molecular species, external fields, etc.

I hope that was helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much sir